# Draw functions on Plot3D

Tags: plotting

I have a 2D function $f(x,z)$ which I render with `Plot3D`. In the plot, on top of the surface, I want to plot 1D functions at $f(0, z)$, $f(100, z)$ and $f(200, z)$.

So far I only have this:

```
um = 1;

Potential[V0_, k_, w_, x_, z_] := V0*(Sin[k z]^2)*Exp[(-2 x^2)/w^2]

mfx = 
  Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate[D[Potential[1, (2 π)/(0.725 um ), 200 um, x, z], x]]];

Plot3D[Potential[1, (2 π)/(0.725 um ), 200 um, x, z], 
   {x, -500 um, 500 um}, {z, -1.1 um, 1.1 um}, 
   PlotRange -> Full, 
   AxesLabel -> {x, z}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50, 
   MeshFunctions -> {mfx}, 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshStyle -> {{Red}}, 
   Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> {True, False, False}, 
   PlotStyle -> Cyan]
```

And I get this:

[image]

This only works for the $x = 0$ bit though.. how can I also add lines at $x = 100, 200$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to indicate the Mesh as a List

```
um = 1;
Potential[V0_, k_, w_, x_, z_] := V0*(Sin[k z]^2)*Exp[(-2 x^2)/w^2]
Plot3D[Potential[1, (2 π)/(0.725 um), 200 um, x, z], 
  {x, -500 um, 500 um}, {z, -1.1 um, 1.1 um}, 
  PlotRange -> Full, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, z}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
  Mesh -> {{0, 100, 200}, {30}, {30}}, MeshStyle -> {{Red}}, 
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> {True, False, False}, PlotStyle -> Cyan]
```

Comment: I have removed the definition of `mfx`since it is not relevant to your solution.

Comment: I suggest `MeshStyle -> {Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[4]]}`. I think it make for a better looking plot.

Comment: adding option `Ticks -> {{-500, 0, 100, 200, 500}, Automatic, Automatic}`

Comment: And would you know how to change the colour each mesh line individally? I tried `MeshStyle->{{Red, Blue, Green}}`